# Issue regarding comparison function in c++ std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14

I was given 2 vectors:

```
vector<int> arrive; 
vector<int> depart;
```

arrive[i] and depart[i] represent the arrival and departure times for different people. My task was to find that at any point of time the no of people should not exceed K(given).

For this I made a `vector<pair<int,int>> arr_dep_time`. This array stored all the points of both arrival and departure arrays. pair.first was to store the time of arrival/departure and pair.second was to store if it is arrival pt(i.e. 0) or departure pt(i.e. 1).

then I used `std::sort(arr_dep_time.begin(),arr_dep_time.end(),comparator)`
I wanted that if I have duplicate times, it should place departure time first. For example, if {5,0} and {5,1} are there,then  {5,1} should be placed before {5,0}. 
So, I wrote comparator as follows:

```
bool comparator(pair<int,int> p1,pair<int,int> p2){
    if(p1.first==p2.first)
      return p1.second>p2.second;

    return p1.first<p2.first;
}
```

But this gave me wrong result on some cases.
However, when I took pair.second as
0:departure 
1:arrival
and wrote comapartor as follows, it gave me correct result.

```
bool comparator(pair<int,int> p1,pair<int,int> p2){
    if(p1.first==p2.first)
      return p1.second<p2.second;
    return p1.first<p2.first;
}
```

can anyone tell me why?

> I have not included the complete solution.Just the part that I
>   felt was necessary.

Comment: maybe because you have a bug here: `return p1.second>p2.second;` in the first `comparator` function?

Comment: @Raffallo What bug? `{5, 1}` is supposed to go *before* `{5, 0}` in first version. Later on OP changed requirements and implementation and it started to work as expected.

Comment: Can you present a [mcve] of your first and failing attempt (with hardcoded sample)? (Please, [edit] your question.)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lmYlNUUAhWcLOimB). I second Scheff's request for a [mre].

Comment: What is the input for the cases with "wrong result"? What were you expecting? What did you get?

Comment: if you want `{5,0} {5,1} -> {5,1} {5,0}`. then you need invert first check to `return p1.second > p2.second;`

Comment: comparator must return `true` if first argument must stay at left and `false` otherwise. also. you should try use `stable_sort` since your logic have multiple paths.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using c++14, perhaps you could use a lambda?

```
std::sort(arr_dep_time.begin(), arr_dep_time.end(), [] (auto &p1, auto &p2){
    return (p1.first==p2.first) ? p1.second < p2.second : p1.first < p2.first;
});
```